# Microsoft report viewer expressions evaluation problem

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, reportviewer

I developed a WinForms tool using VS2017 and report viewer V.14, it worked fine.
But when I tried to evaluate the Font weight or color or back-color using expressions like

```
=IIf(Fields!Value="some text","White","Black")
```

I get the following exception in the reportviewer control in runtime:

> failed to load expression host assembly. details could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. the system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Could be a versioning issue with your ReportViewer reference. Check your referenced assembly version in your project and make sure it's 14.0.0.0. If not, download 14.0.0.0 and copy the dlls to your project folder and reference them locally. Next make sure the "Copy Local" property is set to true on the Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common assembly reference in your project.

Comment: All your comments are already done. still same issue.

Comment: Did you verify the assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll is in your /bin/Debug folder?

Comment: yes I did with no progress